# PHP PDO can select string

Tags: php, select, pdo

I'm a little confused. When I do this below and the username is test@test.com it won't find anything even if the record exists. I realise I need to add quotes but I can't work out where, could someone please point this out.

```
   $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SALT, EMAIL FROM USERS WHERE     USERNAME = :username LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Many thanks

edit: as pointed out below I have tried bindParam as well.

edit 2: solved -I have solved it! I was looking at the wrong column in the DB, sorry guys/girls it's been a long night :( thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you might need to use `bindParam` instead of `bindValue`

Comment: Hey, thanks but I have tried that as well :(

Comment: Have you checked `$stmt->errorInfo()` and `$db->errorInfo()`?

Comment: This is what I get: $stmt->errorInfo() = Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) $db->errorInfo() = 
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: When you do that search directly in the database, do you get a record returned?

Comment: yep, which is what makes me got WTF? If I say change the email to just test and then use that it returns a search result. As soon as I add a @ to it, it doesn't.

Comment: I have solved it! I was looking at the wrong column in the DB, sorry guys/girls it's been a long night :( thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the `username` column is something like `test` and the `email` column has the value `test@test.com`.

If you test for `test@test.com`, I suspect you must compare against the `email` column

```
SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SALT, EMAIL FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = :username LIMIT 1
```

If you really want to test for the username, `$username` should presumably be `test`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow, $username contains test@test.com, I have tested this by echoing it out. In short the email address is the $username.

Comment: @James I tried to clarify the answer. I think username column is not `test@test.com`, but the email column is.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry yes, you are correct. Sorry this is all a bit of mish mash code for the moment, I just need to figure this out :)

Comment: I have solved it! I was looking at the wrong column in the DB, sorry guys/girls it's been a long night :( thanks for your help!